# Can I use PeerJS without a PeerJS Server?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, peerjs

I am trying to make peer-to-peer browser apps with PeerJS, which is a wrapper for the browser technology WebRTC. I spent several hours reading documentation and googling, but I still have no clue what the PeerJS Server is doing.
The documentation of WebRTC mentions STUN and - in certain cases - TURN servers to be required for WebRTC, but there is nothing about additional servers like PeerJS Server. And on the GitHub site of PeerJS Server there is no explanation.
I want to have as little dependencies as possible, so I would rather not use a PeerJS Server. Is there a way to use PeerJS without it? Or do I have to work with raw WebRTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You Can. If You Don't Host Your Own PeerJS Server, then your client will connect to PeerJS cloud. PeerJS cloud is a Server Hosted by PeerJS itself.

You can read it about here: https://peerjs.com/peerserver.html

Comment: My question referred to both, the self-hosted PeerJS servers and the PeerJS cloud. In other words: can I use PeerJS without ANY PeerJS server?
By the way, the PeerJS cloud often rejected my request because of overload, so I think it should only be used for development, not for production.

Comment: Then No, You Can't Because PeerJS Required a PeerJS Server To Work, So that it can send your data from one client to another.